# cabal run pass arguments to program

Tags: haskell, cabal

I can build and run a simple `Haskell` program with `cabal`

```hs
module Main where
import System.Environment ( getArgs )
main :: IO ()
main = do

   -- (input:_:_) <- getArgs
   print "Hello Oren"
```

When *no arguments* are expected, everything goes fine:

```bash
$ cabal build 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
$ cabal run
Up to date
"Hello Oren"
```

It seems possible to pass arguments to the program:

```bash
$ cabal run --help | sed -n '13,16p'
Extra arguments can be passed to the program, but use '--' to separate
arguments for the program from arguments for cabal. The executable is run in
an environment where it can find its data files inplace in the build tree.
```

However, I can't seem to make it work:

```bash
$ cabal run -- Oren 13 10              
cabal: Cannot run the package Oren, it is not in this project (either directly
or indirectly). If you want to add it to the project then edit the
cabal.project file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly call your target that you want to run. For example you can use `exes` as a shorthand if you only have one executable:

```
$ cabal run exes -- Oren 13 10
```

The cabal documentation section on [Target Forms](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-commands.html#target-forms) lists all possible ways to write the target.